# Spring3, Security3: System works on windows but not Linux java.lang.IllegalArgumentException

Tags: java, tomcat, spring-mvc, spring-security

System works on windows but not Linux. I can login ok and list data but once I goto any of the following pages I get the error below:

```
<http auto-config="true" use-expressions='true'>
        <intercept-url pattern="/friends/**" access="ROLE_USER" />
        <intercept-url pattern="/articles/**" access="ROLE_USER" />
</http>
```

java.lang.IllegalArgumentException

```
HTTP Status 500 -

type Exception report

message

description The server encountered an internal error () that prevented it from fulfilling this request.

exception

java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Failed to evaluate expression 'ROLE_USER'
    org.springframework.security.access.expression.ExpressionUtils.evaluateAsBoolean(ExpressionUtils.java:13)
    org.springframework.security.web.access.expression.WebExpressionVoter.vote(WebExpressionVoter.java:34)
    org.springframework.security.access.vote.AffirmativeBased.decide(AffirmativeBased.java:50)
    org.springframework.security.access.intercept.AbstractSecurityInterceptor.beforeInvocation(AbstractSecurityInterceptor.java:203)
    org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:106)
    org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:83)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:380)
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Please see [spring forum](http://forum.springsource.org/showthread.php?t=78426). Expression should be hasRole("ROLE_USER")

Answer (score 3):

In Spring 3.0,it is access="ROLE_USER"

In Spring 4.0 or higher ,it is  access="hasRole('ROLE_USER')"